# Can I return a single error with Promise.allSettled() on a multiple axios post?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-redux, promise

I am sending objects with more than one value in the list to a single api, and I have done this in successive objects as follows.

Redux action:

```
import { axios } from "@lib/axios";

export const addSlot = createAsyncThunk(
  "slot/addSlot",
  async (slots, { dispatch, getState }) => {
    const response = await axios.post(`/slot`, slots);
    return response.data;
  }
);
```

Plan list (example):

```
const plan = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
        "startTime": "08:00 AM",
        "endTime": "09:00 AM"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "dayOfWeek": "Monday",
        "startTime": "08:00 AM",
        "endTime": "10:00 AM"
    }
];
```

Submit function:

```
  const promises = plan.map((obj) => {
    return dispatch(addSlot(obj));
  });

  Promise.allSettled(promises)
    .then((results) =>
      results.forEach((result) => {
        if (result.value.meta.requestStatus === "fulfilled") {
          return toast.success(
            "Slot has been successfully updated."
          );
        } else {
          return toast.error("Slot could not be updated.");
        }
      })
    )
    .catch((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result)));
```

How can I end the Promise.allSettled() function with a single error when any value is entered incorrectly from these objects, rather than giving multiple errors?

Comment: use `.some` to find if any `result.value.meta.requestStatus !== "fulfilled"` ... `if (results.some(result => result.value.meta.requestStatus !== "fulfilled")) { do your error thing }`

Comment: Your `Promise.allSettled(promises)` has already "ended" (resolved) by the time the `then` callback is triggered. If you truly want to end a series of promises when any one errors out, use [`Promise.all(promises)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: @Heretic Monkey The solution shared by j@JaromandaX solved my problem, but I'll try that too, thanks.

Comment: I suggest @JaromandaX answers your question, or you submit an answer to your own question so that people can tell it has been answered.

Comment: Surely you also want only a single success message when all slots could be updated, right?

Answer (score -1):

I used the method @JaromandaX said. And I added it to the Submit function.

> use `.some` to find `if any result.value.meta.requestStatus !== "fulfilled"` ... `if (results.some(result => result.value.meta.requestStatus !== "fulfilled")) { do your error thing }`

Edited Submit function:

```
  const promises = plan.map((obj) => {
    return dispatch(addSlot(obj));
  });

  Promise.allSettled(promises)
    .then((results) =>
      results.some((result) => { // added .some() instead of .forEach()
        if (result.value.meta.requestStatus === "fulfilled") {
          return toast.success(
            "Slot has been successfully updated."
          );
        } else {
          return toast.error("Slot could not be updated.");
        }
      })
    )
    .catch((results) => results.some((result) => console.log(result)));
```